# Best practice using Node: pass a reference or use require import?

Tags: node.js, performance

I'm new to Node.js, can someone explain the advantage and disadvantage of the 2 methods below? Which one should be used?

in app.js:

```
var foo = require("./foo");
var foo2 = require("./foo2");
foo.dostuff();
foo2.dostuff();
```

both foo.js & foo2.js:

```
var needImport = require("./bar");
foo.prototype.dostuff = function()
```

**or**

in app.js:

```
var needImport = require("./bar");
var foo = new require("./foo")(needImport);
var foo2 = new require("./foo2")(needImport);
foo.dostuff();
foo2.dostuff();
```

both foo.js and foo2.js:

```
var needImport;
function foo(needImportPassed) {
needImport = needImportPassed
}
foo.prototype.dostuff = function()
```

The question is basically asking is there an advantage to passing a reference of bar module? or just let the other files request that particular module everytime? (bar.js is not a persistent connection, just a bunch of helper functions, so is bar.js read twice as compared to just once in the second approach?)

Comment: ``require`` uses cache so your module is parsed and executed only once even if you require it several times

Comment: @MatthieuLemoine thanks for answering, I updated the question just now with a better example, can you confirm the above in terms of performance is the same?

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you modify foo prototype. You have two solutions :

in app.js

```
var foo = require('./foo');
var foo2 = require('./foo2');
foo.doStuff();
foo2.doStuff();
```

in foo2.js and foo.js

```
var bar = require('./bar');
module.exports = {
  doStuff : () => bar.doOtherStuff()
};
```

Or

in app.js

```
var bar = require('./bar');
var foo = require('./foo')(bar);
var foo2 = require('./foo2')(bar);
foo.doStuff();
foo2.doStuff();
```

in foo.js and foo2.js

```
module.exports = (bar) => ({
  doStuff : () => bar.doOtherStuff()
});
```

You should use the first solution as it is a more common pattern and it allows to create true modular code. In `app.js` you doesn't need to know which module is needed by foo or foo2.

Comment: I have foo1, foo2......foo100, each require module bar.js, I understand the first approach makes the code easier to understand, but in terms of performance, is there a drawback?